# How to show the full text value in gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

Hi Everyone,
             I bind the datas in gridview in android. but the text not shown in fully. Some letters are hide inside. pls tell how to show the full text in android gridview. I got like this..

Loan Amount  100  10000000 10000, this value only i bind the gridview. but the value of Loan Amount should show only Loan Am other words are hide and one crore value also same like this... I used Relative Layout. Pls tell the solution.

Here is my full layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/Input_lblcomp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="350dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textSize="14pt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/Input_state" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/Input_propslno" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_pdt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_cust" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_lntype" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/txt_unit" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
    android:horizontalSpacing="180dp" >

</GridView>
```

Comment: Can you post Screenshot and How you setting values to GridView post java code.

Comment: Have you tried this android:numColumns="4" to android:numColumns="auto_fit".

Comment: if i give android:numcolumns="auto_fit", it show the single columns all the values shown one by one. I didn't post the screen shot.